# Using "extends" on inferred mapped types in Typescript Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here's my code and the [related playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXBAPMgfFAvFAbwCgooBtAaSgEsA7KAawhDgDMpkBdAfgC4oqEAB7AItACYBnKAHIArjJKko3KJOAAnOgHMlpfskqcow0ROlwARgCsIAY2B7lq%20ElSRMRrE-1QrthyIAXyIiVjlaB2o4eklEFDRMLAAKYH5XBI9sAEpCJQ0IYDkNemAAbmDQ0EgoACEAGQBBPFh49wxiUjl%20AEYAGiVLfk7lbqh%20pSCBoKwKojsY9ShLABsAQwbG-k2WkbH%20qAB6Q6h0AFozqAWNAocTG7gNKARJbQM0WVo5BEsIDRkaNJaHBgFA1pJJNRtLQ1qtoMA4FBqtAZOotLRtDIAHSDYZOfZ9I4nc6Xa63UF-DSPZ6vd41GRfH5-AHUIEgsEQqEwuFIxHI2RonTYybTOYLWhLVZrFpxNxoZJ7XqE46nC5XR7k%205Up4vN4cD4M76-f6AqDA0HgyHQ2EreF8g2CjHC0hDPLKKAEomqy7CSAOCDifiU6lICFrbTQVhUhBgyxwABuEB87q9wAAFtAwFS4TGMwVTem1qD09B42sVnJI9TLFAAO7gqAFOIrRPiXmyfz2YAsiWiNZttiyDLtTwUThYRQplMqtNwWtXNb0ACSUFY1CESLTrO4IuC2QqQA):

```js
type SomeType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: K extends 'u'
    ? string
    : T[K] extends object
      ? SomeType<T[K]>
      : object
}

function someType<T>(t: SomeType<T>) {
  return t;
}

type BLA = SomeType<{
  u: 1,
  b: {
    u: 1,
  },
}>;

const blaBLA: BLA = {
  u: 1, // <-- correct error msg: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  b: {
    u: 1, // <-- correct error msg: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  },
};

const bla = someType({
  u: 1, // <-- correct error msg: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  b: {
    u: 1, // <-- expected: error message from above
          // the problem here is that the value for b was resolved to 'object' instead of 'SomeType<T[K]>'
          // how can I fix this?
  },
});
```

I am either looking for a fix to the problem which I describe in the code above or an explaination why it doesn't work the way I think it works.

As this is purely for learning (understanding) TS, I would be okay with either outcome.

Comment: If you have a function of the form `func<T>(x: F<T>):void` and call `f(x)` then the compiler is going to take `x` as type `F<T>` and try to infer `T` from it.  If `F<T>` is complicated enough, this is going to fail.  Instead it looks like you really want `func<T extends F<T>>(x: T): void`, where `T` is easily inferred from `x`, and then just *checked* against `F<T>`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wye4AW). Does that meet your needs (and I could write up an answer) or am I missing something?

Comment: I just made a comment that your solution doesn't work for arbitrary levels. (This statement was wrong and removed) You're a f genius. Thank you also for the complexity explaination. This absolutely makes sense! (yes, please make an answer out of your comment) <3

Comment: I noticed autocompletion is not working for `someType({ ... })`. This is just a side note. I may ask a seperate question and link it here but I am still "investigating" with my limited skills.

Comment: Fixed it myself. ([Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5PeBw)) I feel like I outsmarted myself.

Comment: Note: I just found the autocomplete solution to not work, when the input to `someType(...)` is correct. [See question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593943/autocompletion-not-working-on-inferred-mapped-types-with-typescript-generics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function like

```
function someType<T>(t: SomeType<T>) {
  return t;
}
```

and call it with `someType(val)`,  then the compiler is going to try to infer the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` given that `val` is of the type `SomeType<T>`.  You're asking the compiler to essentially [*invert*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) the type function `SomeType<T>`.

But that's not really possible for the compiler to do, especially because since `SomeType<T>` might be the same type as `SomeType<U>` even when `T` and `U` are different:

```
type Hmm = SomeType<{ u: 1, b: "", c: { d: "" } }>;
/* type Hmm = {
    u?: string;
    b?: object;
    c?: {d?: object}
} */

type Ugh = SomeType<{ u: true, b: 123, c: { d: false } }>;
/* type Ugh = {
    u?: string;
    b?: object;
    c?: {d?: object}
} */
```

Inverting type functions isn't always possible, or even when it is possible, it's not always feasible for the compiler to do it.

Luckily, this isn't really the behavior you want.

---

Rather, it looks like you would like `SomeType<T>` to act as a [recursive constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) of `T` itself.  What I mean is that when you call `someType(val)`, you want `T` to be inferred as the type of `val`, and then you want the compiler to *check* that `T` is also assignable to `SomeType<T>`.

And so let's just write that directly as a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
function someType<T extends SomeType<T>>(t: T) {
  return t;
}
```

That compiles with no error, so we can proceed to test it:

```
const bla = someType({
  u: 1, // error!
  b: {
    u: 1, // error!
  },
});
```

Looks good.  You get exactly the errors you expect to get.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXBAPMgfFAvFAbwCgooBtAaSgEsA7KAawhDgDMpkBdAfgC4oqEAB7AItACYBnKAHIArjJJRuUScABOdAOZL+ySpyjDRE6XABGAKwgBjYEpXwkqSJgNZdUC9btEAvkREoJBQABIICHiwiCho6ARQcvwAjAA0UOb8AERZ6Tb8CeLZWVB+pVgA3EQA9ABUUMHQ4ZH4xKSkcnyqGtpV7Rld3rbAfe02XQTig1bDAWW11YGNUACqWgAWUU6xrglJDepyEOmZUMkATADMeQVQRVCsAIYANpLQZX6VNfXLa5utSg6XTUmloWlGpHM0x8I0BUHGBSm-CGdjmUAWgSIrDktDs1Dg9EkMRcGGQRhEYik0WccWwWAAFMA9ABKQhKdQQYBydT0WEBIJoKAAIQAMgBBLbEuJtRIpVJKU4yjpypR+eWfKpEGwEtQZZ6PUVi-iGqIy-ZpKDVapQdAAWlt8Lg6g5diMzqdUAQki0ekFMlocgQ5gg6hkNGktDgwCgj0kkmoWloj3Mz2gwDgDT9IO0MgAdAqCnDzekrTb7Y7ncM3eoPV6fRw-QGgyGw9QI1GY3GE0mU2mM8sZNmwXnVerNdraLqU48okSaZB6Wa5ZbrSGa+oAIQFtn9Ysr6tOrekNX+ZlVIA)

Comment: Perfect! Now I have "only" 1 more problem to solve. ([Autocompletion within `someType({...});`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593943/autocompletion-and-argument-inference-not-working-simultaneously-on-mapped-types)) but I am not sure that this is possible after your explaination because it means I cannot really change the signature `(t: T)`. ^.-