# Autocompletion and Argument inference not working simultaneously on mapped types with Typescript generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following code ([Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGVVvm)) I try to make **autocompletion** and **function signature inference** work within `personTypeX({...})` **at the same time** but I can only achieve either of these but not both.

Is it even possible?

Here are the requirements:

- If a person (= the input) has a `firstName`, then it must be a `string`.
- If a person has an `age`, then it must be a `number`.
- ...
- If a person has a property which is neither `firstName`, `lastName`, `age`, `favouriteFood` nor `getLegCount` then the value at that property must itself be a `Person`.

There are 3 overall additional requirements

- Invalid input must be detected (at any level in the input) and marked in the correct location.
  see below: works with `personType1()` and `personType2()`
- Autocompletion for all keys in `firstName`, ..., `getLegCount` must be provided within `personTypeX({})`
  see below: currently only works within `personType2({})`
- If the key (here only `getLegCount`) enforces its value to be a function, then the function signature must be correctly inferred
  see below: currently only works within `personType1({})`

```js
type FixedType = {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  age: number,
  favouriteFood: string[],
  getLegCount: (numHeads: number) => number,
};

type PersonType<T> = {
  [K in (keyof T | keyof FixedType)]?:
    K extends keyof FixedType
      ? FixedType[K]
      : K extends keyof T
        ? T[K] extends object
          ? PersonType<T[K]>
          : PersonType<{}>
        : never
}

// ---- ---- ---- ---- ----

function personType1<T extends PersonType<T>>(t: T) { // signature version 1
  return t;
}

const person11 = personType1({
  firstName: 'Mark',
  lastName: 'Antony',
  holger: {
    age: 12,
    paul: {
      // <-- type 'a' for autocompletion of 'age' => NOT WORKING
      favouriteFood: ['cheese'],
      firstName: 'Paul',
      getLegCount: (numHeads) => 2, // <-- hover over 'numHeads' => numHeads: number correctly inferred => WORKING
    }
  },
});

// ----

function personType2<T extends PersonType<T>>(t: T & PersonType<T>) { // signature version 2
  return t;
}

const person1 = personType2({
  firstName: 'Mark',
  lastName: 'Antony',
  holger: {
    age: 12,
    paul: {
      // <-- type 'a' for autocompletion of 'age' => WORKING
      favouriteFood: ['cheese'],
      firstName: 'Paul',
      getLegCount: (numHeads) => 2, // <-- hover over 'numHeads' => numHeads: any inferred => NOT WORKING
                                    // that's probably bc it's the most common signature for
                                    //   (property) getLegCount: ((numHeads: any) => number) & ((numHeads: number) => number)
                                    // but I have no clue how to fix this
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: I have noticed that you have several similar questions. Could you please provide more information what are you expect from  function argument? What type restrictions should be applied to it ?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering. I created an [improved Playground here](https://tsplay.dev/WGVVvm). This playground demonstrates my problem, that I can either make autocompletion or function argument inference work, but not both at the same time. :(

Comment: I came to the conclusion that this [may be a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49547).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short what you are asking for is impossible at the present moment (as far as my understanding goes).

There is a lot of circular logic here, which it a limitation of TS (and just an affront to humanity in terms of managing/understanding this type of code). We effectively circumvent it using a generic inside a generic, but we are still limited by it. Namely, from my understanding, we can only choose one:

- Retrieve the data type of the parameter, validate and make that the data type of the parameter (**IE. autocompletion**)
- Validate the parameter is suitable, cast upon itself inferenced types (`getLegCount: (numHeads) => 2`), make that the data type of the parameter (**IE. argument inferencing on non-explicit types**)

An example of this is when we go back to how generics are made

```js
function example<T>(t: T)
```

Here we can either explicitly define `T` to prescribe `t` to follow, or we can infer `T` from `t`


When we do something like this:

```js
function personType<T extends PersonTypeNew<T>>(t: T){...}
```

We are making circular logic, and at some point TS has to choose `T` or `t`. (even though they are dependent on each other, they create different outcomes).

- If we infer the arguments (and thereby typing `getLegCount: (numHeads)`, we have inferred `age` to be nothing (because it's not in the arguments), and there is no need to provide autocomplete to `age` (or any other keys).
- Otherwise, the default behavior provides autocomplete

^ This is technically a super super simplification. This is actually supported in simple type objects (ie. non-circular) with something called partial inferencing, which will allow autocomplete and argument inferencing.

If this is confusing, there are some examples in the playground.

Anyways, I rewrote it from the ground up. Supports both autocompletion and argument inferencing, but only the former if the latter isn't present.

```js
type PersonTypeNew<T> = {
  // We have to overwrite any keys, otherwise we could incorrectly infer.
  // Hence Omit<T, keyof FixedType>, we use & Partial<FixedType> for correct autocompletion
  [K in keyof (Omit<T, keyof FixedType> & Partial<FixedType>)]: 
    K extends keyof FixedType
      ? FixedType[K]
      : (Omit<T, keyof FixedType> & Partial<FixedType>)[K] extends Record<string, any>
        ? PersonTypeNew<(Omit<T, keyof FixedType> & Partial<FixedType>)[K]>
        : "Invalid Value!"
}
```

This also adds autocompletion (when you aren't inferencing) on the first layer.

It's a lot more terse without autocompletion support (since we just validate without intersecting two object types)

```js
type PersonTypeNewNoAutocomplete<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: 
    K extends keyof FixedType
      ? T[K] extends FixedType[K]
        ? T[K]
        : FixedType[K]
      : PersonTypeNewNoAutocomplete<T[K]>
}
```

[Check out Playground for Examples](https://tsplay.dev/wXQj9N)

There are open issues discussing this, this goes into further detail on the context engine, priority, other relevant topics to circular types:

- [Incorrect inference/autocompletion on generic arrays, when values can be inferred from a defined object.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41645), generic array instead of generic object (we use a circular generic object), notably this discusses 'priority' of types which may be a better explanation than mine given.
- [Probable bug: Intellisense doesn't work in case of circular type parameter constraints like `T extends M<T>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44428), this discusses how autocomplete doesn't work
- [Reverse mapped type with a circular type param sometimes not treated as partially inferrable](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48798)

Comment: Nice answer @Cody Duong

Answer (score 2):

Check this out, it works by using `Partial<FixedType>` for autocompletion, `K extends keyof FixedType ? FixedType[K]` for error checking and a recursive generic type for nested objects.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/PTAEAkFMCdNB3OBjWBDALnATKAZgVwDsl0BLAe0IGdQADABxisoBUBPRgRltFUIBM6jaM0LtGWHvAAWpJNN4AbReXih00uABFIAN0grh6%20OVApIGOKlAAFJqw5wARqiqRBlUKXQ1ShevjoAHQAUCEgoACSuLygwqKgABQAvOqaXv6BAJSg0q6xtLikIugAcqgAtpC0ADRpkIRe6KAV%20FTNTlag7dB%20AOahEdGx8Z55NHx0qH3VdRoNTS1tHV2E%20BWd0INgkOhI21Ex1qON4yPQ5MLobAiy8l40hJDemtCgAORFJeVV73XvilcZUqkD%20H2moP%20uFQunI%20F6mAAYuRyPx3qBCOQ3u8ZugADKQPoAYThhHQ6PmhHCYHmoF0qEU%20CszQ0GDiFyuN1a7SabkUMU6sTsIkooWpoBYryssFAAGZQOR9NAGYpePx%20N4KIQGaBYABHfDFSBVMlUcWJTg5SKEemKUiCPwBZrclagfi7SAkdxJNl8G6KPQGDL1DJOnJ8QQVVDQADW3r8IaQWNgJFAKiQGC1B1AOe6kGcBlUAC4EFiYzR4C8hPYxI5OIksjwI9WRbWJA3aOasDkAIKBchJir0ANkTy4LFKVVxti%20RqfYrtH6Q0BBVf-XEE4mk8lLHmC%20gXXT272VjQJhg18SQAAaiQA3gBfRvi3N5gsqeAlpDw2BkxQ3Sh-1LWMKxec8TivLB7yfTsIkSWUrRiWlpySKUFUIICcV2TcSSIckcgacdoCQSBfB8OkGSZdRTEFawCGIUdCDmTRGlpeiSC1bpSD6bV0HhOAXVAQUk2gFN0CAvxcBgWB%20BfXM3HfYszB-BpxIAjCbhMECEDAxoL1bK960fZ9xQAWnM0zQAsyzrKsiy7PMsJrkYUBEVIAAPdwr1AVI7xCHMvkXEESx6foan8tMgSXEL0F6Qg%20nCnMIRLNYNhgRK8BhOEEUgZFURiuK%20gAbQAXQyjdCVwskS0SVKoFQfgqBS9ZNhyZIAD4MRa9KQgfABuJzHAlRwiU0JA434a0pJk4VRAAHhYTrUhsaMyAZOa3M8-gr06gAyWxL0cBb2sGlzZocRgFtASB3MwAQaBW6A1sUDaPK8xx2qW0A-JzIqAGlg2ncgYhYEqSwBm67sa0AgZiTb3pcgB%20Vy3u2xx-pK0ASyvUbPQmqaYHcc7CAWjHOt6sJ2MYuJDokK7IYaaHiavY72sSdBsZGsb8cIaaiZrY6cjvUAItgPjoFYgaHzCJNqGaE5OB8mmDMcKCfrwBdgSqEt3gAWWjGM-giwEgu1j4ezJSg2CNnNpHIRQZmgEt1aSmYSwAIk4LB3bqCID09Ug3Gu0SsRoDrQAAdTLfoIpzCqtzwmq6osRq2s6rAMpzehUHwRRndj3N46qjmkmThqqDT0AM9ACI5vM3JFRgBUlQ%20MvGvRcO26a3hCBuSTpO9cOI4AeQAJT%20yJSgAcQLnNa-r5y4HeVB0SI3h%200HYddk44HwRmDvOpH8fJ5n18Aqy%20FvFylF%20BLIr3nkfM3HeMrZ4175go%20Fbc5t3NpZzB84UnwDTCGEIAA)

code:

```
type TypeCheckedInferedPerson<T> = Partial<FixedType> & PersonType<T>

type PersonType<T extends Partial<FixedType>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof FixedType ? FixedType[K] : TypeCheckedInferedPerson<T[K]> 
}

function personType2<T extends PersonType<T>>(t: TypeCheckedInferedPerson<T>) { 
  return t;
}
```

Result:
[image: result]